# How to Store byte[] in a SQLite Database and Select specific byte[] from SQLite Database(Using Android SDK)

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I'm storing int,char,float types as byte[] in the SQLite database, the data is getting saved properly, Now how can we query the database to select a particular byte[] from the database using the Android API's for SQLite?

```
public void retrieveRecord(String firstName) 
{
      byte[] b = firstName.getBytes();
      Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("select * from myTable where firstName='"+b+"'", null);
}
```

Inside Database firstName is TEXT type but it is saved as byte[].
Please help me to modify the above code so that I can query on byte[].

Comment: show us what you have tried..

Comment: How can Convert int int,char,float to byte[] ? Reverse back to same way..

Comment: But I want to query on the database directly using this byte[]

Answer (score 0):

the BLOB type may meet your request.

```
byte[] value = cursor.getBlob(cursor.getColumnIndex(name));
```

and then use ObjectInputStream to deserialize to object.

Comment: But I want to directly query database using byte[] instead of getting it from cursor object.

Comment: @vivek you wanna query byte array with raw sql?  Think twice. It's no need to compel yourself.